If you were to talk about age, how would you say "early 30s", "late 30s", or "mid 30s" in Spanish?
For example:
"That man is in his early 20s"
"That woman is in her mid 40s"
"That person is in their late 50s"
How would you say "early x", "late x", and "mid x" in Spanish when referring to age?

Colloquially you can say

That man is in his early 20s / Ese hombre tiene veintipocos (años)
That woman is in her mid 40s / Esa mujer tiene cuarenta y tantos (años)
That person is in their late 50s / Esa persona tiene cincuenta y muchos (años)

As pointed by mdewey in comments, you can also use suffix -y pico (y becomes i sometimes depending on the decade as you can see in my examples above).
For me, it's not clear in which range I would apply it but probably early or mid. I think that veintipico can be considered as an equivalent of twenty-something.
Click linked words to access DRAE definition for those terms.

Surely 63 fits the definition of "cincuenta y muchos"? :-)

@TomV Yes, it fits. But in most cases it denotes irony. It depends on the context, the person being mentioned, etc ... You can apply it to yourself in a humorous way: "Sí, tengo veintimuchos" (Tengo 37 años pero no lo he asumido todavía). I don't know if English speakers use "late whatevers" in the same way.

Yes we do, but it's more of a stretch linguistically.  The Spanish way of expressing it makes it not even untrue.

In this context I think I have heard y picos but perhaps I misunderstood.

@mdewey You're right but it's not clear for me in which case of the three I would apply it. Maybe it's a good equivalent for twenty-something years old.

Following the order of the question title, it would be:

Early 30's ↦ Treinta y pocos
Mid 30's ↦ Treinta y tantos
Late 30's ↦ Treinta y largos

or more informal:

Trentipocos
Trentitantos
Trentilargos


¿Alguna referencia para el uso de "y largos" que es la única que no había apuntado yo?

Tu respuesta es en base al contenido de la pregunta, solo quise añadir el orden del título, que es sustancialmente diferente. Referencia

Hombre, "sustancialmente" quizás es decir mucho. Aparte que no respetas el orden del título, sino el natural.

Ok, you win  .-

Bueno, no es cuestión de ganar. Si veo bien lo de treinta y largos. El voto negativo no es mío.

Tranqui, no me preocupan los votos negativos. Sólo quise añadir más datos a tu respuesta. El sitio está en declive, el único modo de mantenerlo vivo es colaborando entre todos, aunque algunos persistan en lo contrario.
